# Leaflet Magnifying Glass Plugin - Switching Layers

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have a leaflet map within which I am using the [Magnifying Glass plugin](https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.MagnifyingGlass) and want to switch in and out the layers being magnified. I have one 'basemap' layer and then three layers which I want to Magnify on. I want to be able to change between these layers with three buttons I have setup (Btn1, Btn2, Btn3).

Magnified_Layer1 will automatically be setup with the Magnifying Glass and then the three buttons will then load Magnified_Layer2 and Magnified_Layer3 upon clicking as well as reload Magnified_Layer1. Below is my current code.

I am specifically interested in whether or not there are 'add' and 'remove' methods available for the magnifyingGlass instance or if not, how else I might go about constructing and reconstructing it on the fly with the relevant layers.

```
<div class="span9" style="height:100%">
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="centered" style="width:600px;">
<input type="button" id="Btn1" value="Wealth index" onclick="" class="btnStyle span3" />
<input type="button" id="Btn2" value="PPI" onclick="" class="btnStyle span3" /> 
<input type="button" id="Btn3" value="Income" onclick="" class="btnStyle span3" />

<script>

    // initialize the map + minimum zoom if just focusing on one country
    var map = L.map('map',{minZoom: 7, maxZoom: 7,attributionControl: false,zoomControl: false, scrollWheelZoom:false}).setView([23.814602, 90.413961], 12);
    map.dragging.disable()
    // Add zoom to extent button (see stylesheet and .js file in header)
    <!-- map.addControl(new L.Control.ZoomMin()) -->

    //Setting Maximum bounds for zooming and panning (Top left and bottom right from google maps)
    var bounds = L.latLngBounds([[26.548387, 89.144284], [20.580493, 92.103854]]);
    map.setMaxBounds(bounds);
    map.on('drag', function() {
        map.panInsideBounds(bounds, { animate: false });
    });


    //Load GeoJSON using Ajax Plugin (Chrome not allowing cross HTTP requests..)
    <!-- var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("Bangladesh2.json",{style:style -->
                                            <!-- ,smoothFactor: 0.1}).addTo(map);  -->


    // Adding layers and bounds
    var Basemap_Bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
        new L.LatLng(26.64163201,88.00822613),
        new L.LatLng(20.73330104,92.67489093));

    var Magnified_Bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(
        new L.LatLng(26.6344108958,88.02834),
        new L.LatLng(20.5760799858,92.67000481));


    map.fitBounds(bounds);


    var Basemap = new L.ImageOverlay("img/Basemap.png", Basemap_Bounds).addTo(map);
    var Magnified_Layer1 = new L.ImageOverlay("img/Magnified_Layer1.png", Magnified_Bounds);
    var Magnified_Layer2 = new L.ImageOverlay("img/Magnified_Layer2.png", Magnified_Bounds);        
    var Magnified_Layer3 = new L.ImageOverlay("img/Magnified_Layer3.png", Magnified_Bounds);

// Setting up Magnifying Glass
    var magnifyingGlass = L.magnifyingGlass({
      layers: [Magnified_Layer1],
      zoomOffset: 0,
      radius: 75
    }).addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was using an older version of leaflet (0.7.2) where this function isn't supporting.

I updated to the most current version (1.0.3) and I am now able to switch magnifying glasses using the addLayer and removeLayer functions.